# I am having an issue with the getline function

Tags: c++, string, runtime-error, iostream, substr

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    //set variables
    string name1;string name2;string name3;string n1;string n2;string n3;
    int age1; int age2; int age3;

    //get names and ages
    cout << "Who Is The First Student?"<< endl;
    getline(cin, name1); //name 1
    cout << "What is " << name1<< "'s Age?"<< endl;
    cin >> age1; // age 1
    cout << "Who Is The Second Student?"<< endl;
    getline(cin, name2); //name 2
    cout << "What is " << name2<< "'s Age?"<< endl;
    cin >> age2; //age 2
    cout << "Who Is The Third Student?"<< endl;
    getline(cin, name3); // name 3
    cout << "What is " << name3<< "'s Age?"<< endl;
    cin >> age3; //age 3

    // gets modified names
    n1 = name1.substr(2, name1.size() -3);
    n2 = name2.substr(2, name2.size() -3);
    n3 = name3.substr(2, name3.size()-3);
    // Output formatting
    cout << "Name             Age             Modified"<<endl;
    cout << name1<< "             "<<age1<<"             "<<n1<<endl;
    cout << name2<< "             "<<age2<<"             "<<n2<<endl;
    cout << name3<< "             "<<age3<<"             "<<n3<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output asks the first question which is for the name of the first student but it outputs as this:

Who Is The First Student?-
John Doe-
What is John's Age?-
19-
Who Is The Second Student?-
What is 's Age?-

It is skipping the user input of the second student's name and instantly asking for the age but I don't know why this is happening, is there something wrong with my code or do I have the formatting incorrect? I believe that I used the getline function correctly but I may be incorrect and unaware of it being skipped over by a more important function.

Comment: it will be beacause one of these `n1 = name1.substr(2, name1.size()-3);` results in an incorrect start offset (<0 or > length) or length

Comment: `cin` on a `string` will take input up to the first space or newline. So `name1` will be set to `John`, and your program will attempt to read in `Doe` as `age1`. Use `std::getline` to get lines. However, you can't mix `std::cin >>` and `std::getline` easily. I'd recommend against trying at your level to try to mix them. The best fix action I can recommend is to use names without spaces.

Comment: as per here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr

Comment: Inputting `Doe` as `age1` btw will set `std::cin` to an error state, which will prevent all future input until you clear the error state. The EASIEST fix here is to use names without spaces.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 0):

The [std::string::substr()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) man page says this about the exception you are seeing:

```
Parameters
   pos   -  position of the first character to include
   count -  length of the substring

Exceptions
   [throws] std::out_of_range if pos > size()
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem of the program is that the `operator >>` reads only one word.

That is for example in these statements

```
cout << "Who Is The First Student?"<< endl;
cin >> name1; //name 1
```

You entered a string that contains two words `"John Doe"`. But the `operator >>` reads only the first word `"Jphn"` in the variable `name1`.

So in the next input statement

```
cout << "What is " << name1<< "'s Age?"<< endl;
cin >> age1; // age 1
```

an error occurred because instead of a number the input buffer contains the word `"Doe"`.

So as a result the variables `name1`, `name2`, and `name3` do not contain what you are expecting. And these statements

```
n1 = name1.substr(2, name1.size()-3);
n2 = name2.substr(2, name2.size()-3);
n3 = name3.substr(2, name3.size()-3);
```

produce the run-time error.

Instead of the `operator >>` you should use standard function `std::getline`.

Here is a demonstration program based on the code of your program that shows what is the reason of the error

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string name1, name2;
    int age1;

    //get names and ages
    std::cout << "Input 3 Names Below:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Who Is The First Student?" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> name1; //name 1
    std::cout << "What is " << name1 << "'s Age?" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> age1; // age 1
    std::cout << "Who Is The Second Student?" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> name2; //name 2

    std::cout << "name1 = " << name1 << '\n';
    std::cout << "name2 = " << name2 << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
Input 3 Names Below:
Who Is The First Student?
John Doe
What is John's Age?
Who Is The Second Student?
name1 = John
name2 =
```

As you can see due to the error of reading a data in the variable age1 (the buffer contains the string `"Doe"`) the object `name2` is empty. So if you will use it in this statement

```
n2 = name2.substr(2, name2.size()-3);
```

then the runtime error will occur.

Here is another demonstration program that shows how the standard function `std::getline` can be used in your program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    std::string name1, name2, name3;
    int age1, age2, age3;

    //get names and ages
    std::cout << "Input 3 Names Below:" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Who Is The First Student?" << std::endl;
    std::getline( std::cin, name1 ); //name 1
    std::cout << "What is " << name1 << "'s Age?" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> age1; // age 1
    std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );

    std::cout << "Who Is The Second Student?" << std::endl;
    std::getline( std::cin, name2 ); //name 2
    std::cout << "What is " << name2 << "'s Age?" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> age2; //age 2
    std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );

    std::cout << "Who Is The Third Student?" << std::endl;
    std::getline( std::cin, name3 ); // name 3
    std::cout << "What is " << name3 << "'s Age?" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> age3;

    std::cout << "name1 = " << name1 << '\n';
    std::cout << "name2 = " << name2 << '\n';
    std::cout << "name3 = " << name3 << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
Input 3 Names Below:
Who Is The First Student?
John Dow
What is John Dow's Age?
20
Who Is The Second Student?
Mary Poppins
What is Mary Poppins's Age?
21
Who Is The Third Student?
Bob Fisher
What is Bob Fisher's Age?
25
name1 = John Dow
name2 = Mary Poppins
name3 = Bob Fisher
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with the exception that gets thrown, this is due to and out of range on the substr ca

Comment: @pm100 You are mistaken.

Comment: OK - with that specifc input, but if user enters "ed" as first name even with getline it will still fail . OP has to check lengths

Comment: I used getline and it kind of works. the first output works and I can put in the full name without an error but after the first age is put in, it asks for both the name and age of the second person simultaneously and I am not sure why this is happening

Comment: @jackiscarbon After using the operator >> to enter an age the input buffer contains the new line character '\n' and the next call of getline  reads an empty string. You need to remove the character  line std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );